# How does using log transformation for a confidence interval of the survival stabilizes variance?

Tags: confidence-interval, data-transformation, kaplan-meier, variance-stabilizing

I only found that it eliminates the estimator of survival from the variance formula, but could anyone show some references or write a few formulas to show how exactly the Greenwood becomes more stable here? I'm trying to find a book or article, but they are all paid or don't show this.

Answer (score 0):

In the so-called "plain scale," the Greenwood variance is used to place confidence limits symmetrically around the survival estimate. This can lead to confidence limits that exceed 1 or that are below 0 in small studies.

For example, say that there are 10 at risk at the beginning of the study and one individual has the event. Then at that first event time the estimated survival is 0.9 and the square root of the Greenwood variance is $\sqrt{0.9^2/90} \approx 0.095$. The 95% "plain scale" CI would be $0.9 \pm 1.96\cdot 0.095$, for CI of $(0.71,1.09)$. The top limit is clearly impossible, as survival can't exceed 1.

In the log scale, the CI are based on raising the survival estimate to a power, so they are necessarily between 0 and 1. That isn't so much variance stabilization as ensuring that the CI are within realistic bounds.